# Why would Yii2 delete a SESSION entry in the DB after a "GET" or "POST" request?

Tags: php, session, yii2

I have two branches of the same project. There are minor differences between these two branches but something in the one branch is causing my SESSION entry (which I store in the DB) to be deleted on any kind of "GET" or "POST" request - whether it's clicking a link or simply performing a browser refresh. I do not experience this behaviour in the other branch.

- I have not altered any permissions.
- I have not added extra `actions` in my controller that I would need to add permissions for.
- There are exactly three files that differ from the one branch to the other - a view, a controller, and a model.
- The `view` differs only in changed variable names - for which I do not get an `undefined` error in the browser so that should be fine.
- In the `controller` I have only broken up the processes one of the `action` methods so that other methods are called to process difference bit of code, but always returning to the same `action` to `render` the said `view`.
- I do not empty the session at any point in any other part of my code.
- I do set session variables but they are all correctly stored in the same `__flash` entry in the db - up until the point where that entry is whacked from the DB.

The effect of having my SESSION entry deleted from the DB is that it then causes a check for `adminId` in the `$_SESSION` to fail which fires a `denyCallback` redirecting me to `localhost`.

I have debugged almost everywhere where there is mention of `$_SESSION` or `Yii::$app->session`, as well as everywhere in `yii2/web/Session.php`. And after hours I could not find a single instance where it actively empties the `$_SESSION` variable and then saving it to the DB.

I thought it might be something to do with pjax calls, but that cannot be as I have those same calls in the one branch where the session entry is always preserved.

It seems to be that something is failing on the requests and the browser just keeps on retrying until it eventually gives up and then somehow, somewhere deletes my SESSION from the db. I'm out of theories.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could it be that both your applications are located on the same domain (localhost) and that logging in to both of them causes an invalid session key and a automatic logout/session delete?

Comment: Jorgen, I'm running PHP Storm - and every time I switch a branch and launch the application I either stop the previous one or I simply click rerun and phpstorm terminates the previous session automatically. Do you think there could be something buggy with phpstorms termination of applications?